# Have I really downloaded a virus or is my AV software overreacting?

Tags: anti-virus, virus

I have had the download and installation of Glassfish OpenESB stopped/interrupted three times now by F-Secure Anti-Virus.

The virus it has found is "gen:heur.minggy".

I haven't found much online for the minggy virus. I am guessing, judging by the name, that it was a heuristic getting a false positive, but I would like a definite answer.

The download came from here:
http://www.logicoy.com/sites/default/files/glassfishesb-v2.2-full-installer-windows.exe

When I actually managed to download this file without the AV interrupting, the installation was interrupted at the time of the installation of the uninstaller.

Answer (score 7):

I can't comment on the exe itself, but the name of the (alleged) virus indicates that it was detected by a *heuristic* scan, i.e. your AV software can't exactly detect and confirm a virus, but the executable does something that viruses usually might do.

*If* you trust the source of the file, it's probably just a false positive. If you're not absolutely sure, I would recommend checking with other AV software to see if they detect anything.

Answer (score 1):

Check the results here:

http://www.virustotal.com/url-scan/report.html?id=b47db08d41acc8b2a9c0da66e8da7594-1300787563